# Is it no longer possible to resize a Firefox window below a certain threshold width?

Tags: firefox, width

I'm using the latest Firefox testing a fluid layout.

Somehow after the last update of FireFox, I seem to no longer be able to shrink the page width below a certain threshold level (in my case 348px). Even if I delete all elements on the page, I'm still at 348px.

I have tried to hide all toolbars and Firefox buttons, but still no change.

If check a page in Chrome, the HTML width gets reported correctly = whatever my browser window is resized to.

**Question*: 
Is this a new "feature"/setting? If so, can I turn this off... It's annoying for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 14 (if I remember correctly) should have a responsive layout tool - you might want to check that out.

Comment: cool. Thanks for the answer. Should be out with FF15. I managed to fix my browser window by removing the Google Toolbar from the browser. Used to shrink away, seems to stay at fixed-min-width on FF14+